# remove array in resource collection lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm still a beginner at using lumen

I wanna ask, how to remove this array from resource in lumen
this is my controller :

```
public function language($id){
    $languages = Language::where('id', $id)->get();
    return LanguageResource::collection($languages)->additional(['MESSAGE' => 'SUCCESS', 'STATUS' => '200']);
 }
```

this is my resource :

```
class LanguageResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        self::$wrap = 'DATA';

        $pages = ManagePage::all();

        $managepage = [];
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            foreach($page->label as $label){
                $managepage[$page->page_name_variable][$label->label_name] = 
                $label->langtext($this->id)->pluck('text')[0];
            }
        }
        return
        [
            'language_name' => $this->name,
            'language_code' => $this->language_code,
            $this->merge($managepage),
        ];
     }
 }
```

from my code I got this :

```
{
"DATA": [
    {
        "language_name": "English",
        "language_code": "lang-English",
        "page-login": {
            "button-add": "add",
            "button-delete": "delete"
        }
    }
],
"MESSAGE": "SUCCESS",
"STATUS": "200"
}
```

I'm trying to get a return like this, without `[ ]` on DATA :

```
{
"DATA":
    {
        "language_name": "English",
        "language_code": "lang-English",
        "page-login": {
            "button-add": "add",
            "button-delete": "delete"
        }
    }
"MESSAGE": "SUCCESS",
"STATUS": "200"
}
```

can some one help me ? 
I am very grateful for those who want to help me .. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot one thing.

`self::$wrap = 'DATA'; //can you comment this code and then try this.`

```
$managepage = [];
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    foreach($page->label as $label){
         $managepage['DATA'][$page->page_name_variable][$label->label_name] = 
         $label->langtext($this->id)->pluck('text')[0];
     }
}
```

Tell me if this helps.

Comment: if i use your code, i got like this :                                                                                                   {
    "data": [
        {
            "language_name": "English",
            "language_code": "lang-English",
            "DATA": {
                "page-login": {
                    "button-add": "add",
                    "button-delete": "delete"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "MESSAGE": "SUCCESS",
    "STATUS": "200"
}